# why $\lim_{M\to\infty} e^{-kM}=0$

Tags: limits, infinity

why $\lim_{M\to\infty}  e^{-kM} = 0$ if $k>0$

I know that $e^{-\infty} = 0$

but why
$e^{-k\infty} = 0$

I was told I could not do operations with infinity

Comment: If $M$ tends to infinity, and $k > 0$, does $kM$ also tend to infinity? What does it tell you about the values of $e^{-kM}$ as $M$ tends to infinity?

Comment: I wonder why you were "told you could not do operations with infinity". If (as I do) you feel legit to write $e^{-\infty} = 0$, you can also safely write $$\forall k>0,\quad -k\infty=-\infty.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval  you are multiplying infinity times negative one

Comment: Indeed, and with no shame. This equality is just a shorthand for what @Alex hinted you in his comment above.

Comment: $e^{-kM}=e^k e^{-m}=$ something positive multiplied by $e^{-m}$

Comment: There are so many exceptions and loopholes in "infinity arithmetic" that one should train oneself to *always* translate it into the language of limits and rigorously stated limit theorems.

Comment: @MasB ? If you mean $e^{-kM}=e^ke^{-M}$, this is wrong.

Comment: @MasB but $e^{-kM}=e^{-k}e^M$ as well so this doesn't work.

Comment: @CyclotomicField $e^{-kM}\color{red}\ne e^{-k}e^M$ as well.

Comment: @AnneBauval what am I even doing. Of course not. Thanks.

Comment: @samsamradas $k\infty$ (for $k\in\Bbb R$) is an indeterminate form only if $k=0$. If $k>0$ then $k\infty=\infty$. If $k<0$ then $k\infty=-\infty$. Also, $e^{-\infty}=0$ and $e^\infty=\infty$. These are only notations for $\lim\dots$. For instance, $(-1)\infty=-\infty$ means: $\lim_{x\to\infty}(-1)x=-\infty$.

Comment: thank you......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is only true for $k>0$, in this case you can use the fact that $x^k$ is continuous and so

$$\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} e^{-kM} = \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} (e^{-M})^k = \left(\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} e^{-M}\right)^k = 0^k = 0$$